# Access violation using THTTPGet with OpenSSL under iOS after upgrading to XE7 update 1

Tags: ios, delphi, ssl, indy, delphi-xe7

After upgrading to Delphi XE7 update 1 I am seeing the following error when connecting to a server using TIdHTTP with TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project Test_iOS raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 8FE090C9, accessing address C03F1E32'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help   
---------------------------
```

The exception is thrown at line 3133 in IdSSLOpenSSL.

Tested and works fine on Windows and Android platforms.

Before the upgrade everything worked correctly. I also updated to XCode 6.1 at the same time, so perhaps this is part of the problem.

Anybody else seeing a similar error? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Does it also AV if you run the client on Windows?

Comment: I suggest to add the Indy tag (seems to be unrelated to FireMonkey, HTTP does not depend on the GUI).

Comment: @mjn - I updated the question - Tested and works fine on Windows and Android platforms.

Comment: Reported to EMB: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9758

Comment: I use the method found here and it works okay on IOS: http://www.monien.net/delphi-xe5-ssl-https-on-different-platforms-with-tidhttp-and-trestclient/ However, with GZIP enabled something doesn't work quite right.

Comment: @FMXExpress - I tried turning off GZIP, but still get the error. BTW, are you using XE7 update 1? Everything worked fine before I updated. Where did you find your iOS OpenSSL files?

Comment: Yes, using XE7 Update 1 here with http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/OpenSSLStaticLibs.7z Without gzip everything works fine. With gzip I get ssl3_read_bytes issues. Sometimes. And depends on the server too. Two different Azure web server configurations behave differently.

Comment: I am using IOS7.1 though and don't know which Xcode version. I assume Xcode 5.1.1 (MacInCloud). Maybe we need new static libraries built in Xcode 6?

Comment: You can post an answer with the link to the bug report (and accept it)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with xE7 - I'm in the pub so don't have the actual file names in my head.

But you need to download the open ssl files (there's 2) and stick them in the root of your project.

All worked fine after that. My error was because the open ssl was not shipped with xe7.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There was an iOS HTTPS issue in XE7 that should have been addressed in the update. This is likely the reason you are seeing the issue. I think the OpenSSL libraries need to be updated, but can search for more details and let you know...